# Ошибка при написании программы на C++ "выражение должно иметь константное значение"

Tags: c++

Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void verb()
{
    cout << "verb" << endl;
}
void substantiv()
{
    cout << "substantiv" << endl;

}
void adjectiv()
{
    cout << "adjectiv" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    do{
        string intro;
        cout << "Scrie si vrei si stii: ";
        cin >> intro;
        switch (intro) {
        case (intro == "verb"):
            verb();
            break;
        case (intro = "substantiv"):
            substantiv();
            break;
        case (intro ="adjectiv"):
            adjectiv();
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Nu am gasit nik :( scrii pi ok.ru Alin S si am si adaug" << endl;
            break;
        }
        /*if (intro == "verb") {
            verb();
        }else if (intro == "substantiv") {
            substantiv();
        }else if (intro == "adjectiv"); {
            adjectiv();
        }*/
    } while (true);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: а где вы так учились case писать? и да, = и == это совсем разные вещи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код некорректный с точки зрения синтаксиса и грамматики языка C++.

Вы можете использовать следующий подход

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

//...

const char * words[] =
{
    "verb", "substantiv", "adjectiv",
};

enum Words : size_t { Verb, Substantiv, Adjectiv };

std::string s("verb");

auto it = std::find(std::begin(words), std::end(words), s);

size_t n = std::distance(std::begin(words), it);

switch ( n ) 
{
case Verb:
    verb();
    break;
case Substantiv:
    substantiv();
    break;
case Adjectiv:
    adjectiv();
    break;
default:
    std::cout << "Nu am gasit nik :( scrii pi ok.ru Alin S si am si adaug" << std::endl;
    break;
}
```

Comment: спасибо я еще новичок и не углублился в С++ все еще учу

Comment: @AlinStirbu Не за что. Спрашивайте еще.:)

Answer (score 0):

В *C++* оператор `switch` не позволяет использовать для выбора строки. Но можно реализовать для строк некий аналог `switch` при помощи `std::map`. Например, так:

```
#include <map>

// ...

const map<const string, void (*)()> functions = {
    {"verb",       verb},
    {"substantiv", substantiv},
    {"adjectiv",   adjectiv}
};

do {
    cout << "Scrie si vrei si stii: ";
    string intro;
    cin >> intro;
    auto it = functions.find(intro);
    if (it != functions.end())
        (*it->second)();
    else
        cout << "Nu am gasit nik :( scrii pi ok.ru Alin S si am si adaug" << endl;
} while (true);
```